# Как связать таблицы Многие ко Многим в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Помогите разобраться со Связями Многие ко Многим в Laravel
Вроде бы по документации делаю но что то немного не понимаю (совсем не понимаю..).
Как мне например при добавлении нового фильма в таблицу films связать его с актером из таблицы actors? Связь должна быть по filmid, actrid

В документации вообще дан подобный пример, но как он создает связь ведь он просто добавляет запись в таблицу. не понятно..
Film::create(['filmid'=>123, 'name_ru'=>'Какой то фильм 2']);

У меня есть таблица films

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFilmsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('films', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('filmid')->unsigned()->unique();
            $table->string('name_ru')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
}
```

Таблица Actors

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateActorsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('actors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('actorid')->unsigned()->unique();
            $table->string('name_ru')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }
}
```

В таблице есть какие то актеры например:
1|11|Актер 1
2|22|Актер 2
3|33|Актер 3

И таблица FilmActor

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFilmActorsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('film_actors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('filmid')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('actorid')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->foreign('filmid')->references('filmid')->on('films')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('actorid')->references('actorid')->on('actors')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
}
```

Вот модель Films

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Film extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'films';

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'filmid',
        'name_ru',
    ];

    public function actors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Actor', 'film_actors', 'actorid', 'filmid');
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос ссылку на упомянутую вами документацию. Ну и версию Laravel.

Comment: @РустамГимранов  https://laravel.demiart.ru/many-to-many-relationship/ https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many Версия 6,0

Comment: Зачем вы в таблице `films` создаете `filmid`, если уже есть `id`? Зачем вы в таблице `actors` создаете `actorid`, если уже есть `id`? Почему в таблице `film_actors` вы не указываете пробел перед `id`: `actorid`, `filmid`?

Comment: Сначала создаете фильм в БД, а потом прикрепляете массив идентификаторов `id` актеров к фильму https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: @РустамГимранов Мне нужна связь, не по ID а по actorid и filmid
пробую делаю вот так: 
$film = Film::create([
    'filmid'  =>  123,
    'name_ru' =>  'Фильм 1',
]);
//$actors = Actor::where('actorid', '=', 11)->get();
$actors = Actor::find([1,2]);
$film->actors()->attach($actors);

Comment: @РустамГимранов Но у меня возникает ошибка, т.к. пытается сделать связку по id, а не по filmid и actorid

Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`kino`.`film_actors`, CONSTRAINT `film_actors_filmid_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`filmid`) REFERENCES `films` (`filmid`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `film_actors` (`actorid`, `filmid`) values (1, 1), (1, 2))'

Comment: @РустамГимранов не пойму как переопределить поля для связки не по id